# icons - How does one create your own icon set?

Tags: icon, software-recommendation, open-source

I tried looking over StackExchange a lot, but couldn't find anything related to my question :(

I have seen many (**MANY**) icon sets evolve from being nothing to everything. A few days ago I have seen BootStrap Icons, and they looked nice!

So, how *do* people create their own icon sets?

- Is there a very popular tool they use?
- Do they hand-code the icons?

P.S. I am **VERY** new to Stack Exchange, so please do point out any mistakes I have made in my question...

EDIT:

I would also like the software to be freely downloadable, or at-least a free version with features enough for an average human to understand and use. A web platform *is preferred*, but not **completely necessary** if it is open-source. I would like to license the icons I make, under my own license of choice too!

Comment: ...you draw them in a vector application like Illustrator (commercial) or Inkscape (open source). And: hi, welcome to GDSE! Have a look that the [help] if you're stuck or confuzzled!

Comment: @Vincent

I would really like a FOSS software like Inkscape, not illustrator :(

*Personal question: is inkscape good? i have seen lots of software that's just software in terms of name. i want software in terms of use for what it is designed*

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with 'software in terms of name', but I can confirm that Inkscape is very decent at what it does. You need to wrap your head around the vector-oriented drawing thing, but then it's great.

Comment: Oh. So I think I should give Inkscape a shot. By that term I meant Dumbware (a new word?) (it means software that doesn't do what it's supposed to do)

Comment: (P.S. Thanks for the retag :)

Comment: Inkscape is passable, and goid for breaking copyprotection. But a bit painful for day to day work.

Comment: @joojaa and Vincent, on a scale of 1 to 5, how hard would you rate the *vector drawing thing*? (1 = Easy as pie!, 5 = Harder than Stone!)

Comment: Depends on what you want

Comment: After practicing intensively say a week it's easy as pie for drawing everything that you can imagine (including the details) before seeing it.  Like any drawing method it becomes harder than stone if you start to expect that the program brings for you the details that you cannot imagine before seeing them.